# Is there an upper-limit for sparticle masses?

Tags: supersymmetry, large-hadron-collider, beyond-the-standard-model

I realize there are many flavors to supersymmetry theory but can the LHC reach the energy and luminosity levels past which if sparticles are not detected then supersymmetry can definitively be ruled out?

Asked in a slightly different way: does string theory predict that sparticles must necessarily be of a range of mass in order to make the theory consistent and does the LHC have enough energy and luminosity to reach that level? Case in point: it took 100 years for technology to advance to the point where gravitational waves were first discovered after predicted by Einstein. Is this a similar case or is the LHC designed to rule out sparticles if they are not there?

Comment: More on [SUSY at LHC](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/supersymmetry+large-hadron-collider).

Comment: I don't know how to close the question.  Qmechanic has pointed  to a similar question that mine is a duplicate of therefore this is a duplicate question and should be deleted or tagged as duplicate.   By the way the answer to the duplicate question was that it was too broad so I must assume that mine is out of bounds.  Thank you

Comment: What duplicate?

Comment: Qmechanic pointed me to more on susy at lhc.  Great info.  ! I enjoyed reading it but I assume he pointed out similar questions to let me know my question was already addressed. I assume this means maybe my question can be considered a duplicate.  All in all this sounds like susy and sparticles are  one of those theories that no experimental equipment currently designed can disprove.